# How to replace column text in SQL Table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have column called `CommPostCommUrl` in table `CommunitiesPostings` has text value.

```
CommPostCommUrl
--------------------
http://communities.site.com/TIGS
http://communities.site.com/TIGS
http://communities.site.com/Leaders
http://communities.site.com/Specialty
http://communities.site.com/Specialty
http://communities.site.com/PN
http://communities.site.com/TIGS/SIM
```

Replace column text to

```
CommPostCommUrl
--------------------
http://communitiesdev.site.com/TIGS
http://communitiesdev.site.com/TIGS
http://communitiesdev.site.com/Leaders
http://communitiesdev.site.com/Specialty
http://communitiesdev.site.com/Specialty
http://communitiesdev.site.com/PN
http://communitiesdev.site.com/TIGS/SIM
```

Please provide me Query

Comment: seriously http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862(v=SQL.90).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE Table
SET CommonPostURL = REPLACE(CommonPostURL , 
                            'http://communities.',
                            'http://communitiesdev.')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE CommunitiesPostings
SET CommPostCommUrl = REPLACE (CommPostCommUrl,'communities','communitiesdev')
```